# DALI Lighting (IEC62386-209) and Command-In-Between

Tags: electrical, lighting, dali

Good Afternoon,

I'm having some trouble understanding IEC62386-209 section 12.7.3, which involves sending an "ENABLE DEVICE TYPE 8" command to DALI Control Gear prior to sending an extended (DT8) command.

The paragraph in question for the associated test sequence:

> **12.7.3.1** Test sequence 'ENABLE DEVICE TYPE: Application extended commands' An application extended command shall be executed only if
>   preceded by command 272 'ENABLE DEVICE TYPE 8'. If there is a command
>   in-between command 272 and the application extended command the
>   application extended command has to be ignored unless the command
>   in-between is addressed to another control gear. The test sequence is
>   shown in Figure 85.

My issue is in understanding what happens when an in-between command is sent on the bus, directly after ENABLE DEVICE TYPE 8 (such that it's essentially interrupted)

From what I gather, and according to the paragraph above, the extended command has to be ignored, unless the in-between command is addressed to a different device.

In that case, what happens if the in-between command is not sent to another device, but a device group which the device is or isn't part of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the command in-between the ENABLE DEVICE TYPE 8 and the application extended command addresses this device, that aborts the application extended command sequence hence the test shows that QUERY COLOUR TYPE FEATURES should **not** be responded to for addresses Broadcast, Short Address 1 or Group Address 1 because the device under test has these addresses in the example test case.

For the cases where the command in-between does not address this device, that command is discarded so the application extended command sequence operates as if there were no command in-between. In the example test case, this means there is a response to the QUERY COLOUR TYPE FEATURES when the command in-between is addressed to Short Address 2 or Group 2 because the device under test does not have these addresses.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was after